# Using JavaHelp with a web app

Tags: java, web-applications, javahelp

We have a system where our front end is either a Rich Client application or a web interface into the back end.  We are working on adding context-sensitive help to our system, but we need to use the same base configuration files - i.e. the context-sensitive help files would need to be the same, and preferably use the same system.  I was looking into JavaHelp, which seems to use xml/xhtml files for its formatting.  Does anyone know if it is usable in a web-based application, or if you should only expect it to be usable in a rich client setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaHelp can be used in server based applications, see [here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/jhug.pdf) - section 5.7 Server−Based JavaHelp Helpsets (page 112)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am having our web guys look at it to see if it integrates in with their current application design, or if we can integrate it in in some fashion.